# SMPP ERROR 13 - ESME_RBINDFAIL

Tags: java, smpp, opensmpp

i'm using smpp 3.4 to sending short message, when i sent connecting request to SMSC i got the code stats (0x0d - 13 - ESME_RBINDFAIL). but it's work with an other SMSC.

can some one help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMSC sends this error code for various reasons like the requested bind request type is not supported or bad credentials, mis-matched zone or account not smpp enabled.

Comment: it was SYSTEM_TYPE  not supported, i do it with living SYSTEM_TYPE empty and it'is working now

Comment: Now i have a problem with receiving messages from the same SMSC, when i try to receive message i got this error 'ValueNotSetException' that mains there is some optionnal params empty in the request pdu

Comment: Sorry for the late response.This exception usually arises when you have requested some optional parameter and the SMSC doesn't give the requested optional parameter.

Comment: the problem is the message id the smsc not send it, i open an other question here if you have an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732729/receive-message-from-smsc-using-opensmpp

Answer (score 1):

Usually ESME_RBINDFAIL corresponds whith a wrong (or missing) configuration at the SMSC side, for example, an ip filter configuration. Have you checked with the SMSC that all the configuration wich you are using is right?